# How to access a private Gitlab maven repository from a azure devops pipeline?

Tags: maven, azure-devops, gitlab, azure-devops-pipelines

How can I access a private maven Repository at Gitlab during my java build in an azure pipeline that has a dependency to a jar file in the repo at Gitlab?

There is this MavenAuthenticateV0 task but that expect the maven config to be in the following format:

```
<server>
    <id>feedName</id>
    <username>Authorization</username>
    <password>token</password>
</server>
```

While Gitab expects:

```
<server>
  <id>feedName</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
      <property>
        <name>Authorization</name>
        <value>token</value>
      </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Does the MavenAuthenticateV0 task not work? Does replacing Gitlab expects format into setting.xml work?  You can try to specify setting.xml in the option argument of maven task: `options: '--settings .mvn/settings.xml'`. Here is the [case](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/333) you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks @HughLin-MSFT, I wasn't aware of this option, I will play with it and let you know if it works for me

Comment: I think it seems to work, just fighting with the credentials, but it seems to work, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that this workaround works, I will convert the comment to an answer. If this answer is helpful, you could consider to accept it. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround , you can try to specify `setting.xml` in the `option` argument of maven task:

```
- task: Maven@1
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: deploy
    options: '--settings .mvn/settings.xml'
```

Here is a [ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/333) you can refer to.